# Disallowing Delegated admin users to delete resources

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, admin, policy

I am working as Azure partner support person where I have delegated admin access to multiple users tenant.
recently we faced a scenario where one of the production resource got deleted by mistake from a colleague.
Can you please suggest me a way where I can disallow delegated admin users to delete resources.

Just for heads up I have tried Lock feature which was causing problems to client users to make some changes.

Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe a custom RBAC role could be used that gives needed permissions but doesn't give delete action permission?

Answer (score 0):

RBAC is a better solution in this case. RBAC is more user focused where Policy is more resource focused.